# Can Corda resist distortion or manipulation？

Tags: corda

We know that Corda is not a real blockchain system although it uses some technologies inspired by blockchain.

So I have a question: can Corda resist distortion or manipulation like Bitcoin or Ethereum? Is Corda suitable for electronic contract deposit?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Steve i tested technically this scenario [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47918053/corda-data-tampering-issue), basically Corda is for privately own networks where most of the cases the participants have to agree the terms & conditions from the owner/ central party unlike public blockchains.

Comment: Hi Rickky, what do you mean by "agree the terms & conditions" here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

In Corda, the ledger is updated via *transactions*. Each transaction has a set of *required signers*. All the required signers must sign a given transaction with their private keys for the transaction to be considered a valid update to the ledger.

If the transaction is modified in any way after the signatures have been applied, the signatures will no longer match the contents of the transaction, and the transaction will no longer be valid. In this way, manipulation of the data is resisted.