# what should be expected if i tamper the h2 database in corda?

Tags: java, h2, blockchain, corda

what happen if i tamper the data in h2 database

I have  tampered with some hex strings but corda continued to work without any problem. i don't understand, how is that possible?

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you think maybe you're running into the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/a/47941033/8824032

Comment: no i did not commented out the contract code just like he did thanks anyways

Comment: Maybe you can write in detail how you tampered the data. Its likely you tampered the irrelevant tables.

Comment: Can you try using the state (whose data you say is tampered) as an input state in any transaction and see what happens ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Corda Data Tampering Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47918053/corda-data-tampering-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what is being tampered with.

If you tamper with the ID of an input state, for example, then other nodes should reject transactions involving that state.

However, if you modify the hash of an attachment stored locally, you will only be affecting yourself (and any other nodes you share the attachment with). The issues could not become evident for some time.

Comment: what is the expected behavior of corda if it detects the tampering

Comment: It really depends on which piece of data you modify. For example, modifying a state will have a different impact to modifying an attachment or the network map.

Comment: can you refer me to some documentation that explains how corda will behave if i tamper the data or shutdown the node

Comment: There isn't an overview currently. It's very hard to say in general what will happen if you randomly interfere with a program's data. If you want details on a specific change to a specific table, please raise a new question :)