# Corda States storage

Tags: corda

I am referring to corda opensource version and the link

[Corda Data Tampering Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47918053/corda-data-tampering-issue)

When I go through the comments , its mentioned that each node stores states in two places - on their own in its **vault** , and as part of the transactions that generated them in its **transaction storage**.

I could see the state in the first place, i.e vault ,using web interface that connects to the H2 database

I am trying to understand how do I see the state in the second place, i.e the transaction storage. Where it is located physically ?

Answer (score 1):

The transactions are stored in the `NODE_TRANSACTIONS` table in the node's database. However, they are stored as serialised blobs, rather than in human-readable form.